# Absolute value for column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, absolute-value

How could I convert the values of column `'count'` to absolute value?

A summary of my dataframe this:

```
               datetime       count
0   2011-01-20 00:00:00   14.565996
1   2011-01-20 01:00:00   10.204177
2   2011-01-20 02:00:00   -1.261569
3   2011-01-20 03:00:00    1.938322
4   2011-01-20 04:00:00    1.938322
5   2011-01-20 05:00:00   -5.963259
6   2011-01-20 06:00:00   73.711525
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.abs()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'count':[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3]})

df['count'] = df['count'].abs()

print(df)
   count
#0      1
#1      1
#2      2
#3      2
#4      3
#5      3
```

Comment: what if I want to maintain the datetime as my first column?

Comment: @Mwspencer just make a new column: `df['abs'] = df['count'].abs()`

Comment: Get `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `abs()` on multiple columns too.

```py
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].abs()
```

or use numpy `abs()` as well, which interestingly returns a pandas object, not a numpy array:

```py
df['col1'] = np.abs(df['col1'])
```

---

On a tangential note, if you get `SettingWithCopyWarning` when you convert column values into absolute values, that means your dataframe is probably created by filtering another dataframe. Turn on copy-on-write mode to turn it off. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76312603/19123103) for more info.

```py
pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True

df['count'] = df['count'].abs()
```

or use `assign()` to make a copy.

```py
df = df.assign(count=df['count'].abs())
```