# How to use Math's Mod function Ex:- |-x|=x in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, math

I have a dataframe that contain some data.

```
import pandas as pd
start = time.time()
data_store = pd.read_excel("101010.xlsx")
print(data_store)

A                      B
100                    -200
100                    -99
200                    -150
100                    150
50                     -60
70                     50
80                     -100
25                     15
30                     40
50                     -25
```

I want to apply Math's Mod function in python pandas dataframe and print that result.

Ex:- |-200| = 200

Please can some body help me how i can apply this function in python pandas dataframe.

Thank you in advance :) :) :)

Comment: Do you think absolute values? `df.B.abs()`? Or modulo? What is expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 0):

- python: 3.8.5
- pandas: 1.1.1
- xlrd: 1.2.0

Reference:

1. [pandas.DataFrame.abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html)
2. [Absolute value for column in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077188/absolute-value-for-column-in-python)

```
import pandas as pd
data_store = pd.read_excel('101010.xlsx')
data_store.B = data_store.B.abs()  # Absoulte value of Column B
print(data_store)

   A    B
0  100  200
1  100   99
2  200  150
3  100  150
4   50   60
5   70   50
6   80  100
7   25   15
8   30   40
9   50   25
```